# C++ Sorting an array with multiple value types using a single function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have an array of Record objects where each record stores the first name, last name, GPA, email, and ID Number of a student. I need to create one function that can sort the records based on any of the fields it has. However, I run into trouble because the different values have different variable types(int, string, double). Is there a way to dictate which value of the array gets passed to the sorting function?

I have tried creating templates, enums and other things. However, even with a template class function where I can indicate the type of value passed I still cant pass only first names or GPAs to it, for example. Even with the template function I need to use records[i].GPA in the function so it knows to compare GPAs. My instructor said we need a function that can compare any of them and that we can't copy paste the function for different values i.e. a sorting funtion for records[].firstName a different one for recrods[].lastName etc... We also aren't allowed to use `#include<algorithm>`.

Basically I need to be able to pass a distinct variable that is part of an object array and have the sorting function sort the objects passed on the variable selected. I am pretty new to programming so any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Are you basically re-asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402637/how-sort-an-array-of-objects-regardless-of-object-variable-type)? If so, maybe you could explain the new problem you're facing more specifically.

Comment: @Chipster seems we should check old questions of OPs too in future :)

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007976/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-c-sharp-var-keyword-in-c-cli) try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Sort an array of objects regardless of object variable type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56402637/how-sort-an-array-of-objects-regardless-of-object-variable-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use C++'s standard sort function, `std::sort`, declared in the `<algorithm>` header with a user defined predicate.

Here is an example:

```
struct A{
      int a1;
      int a2;
      string a3;
};

bool predicate(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a1 != rhs.a1)
        return lhs.a1 < rhs.a1;
    if (lhs.a2 != rhs.a2)
        return lhs.a2 < rhs.a2;
    return lhs.a3 < rhs.a3;
}
```

Or as suggested by @[Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9528746/max-langhof) you can use [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie):

```
bool predicate(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) {
        return std::tie(lhs.a1, lhs.a2, lhs.a3) < std::tie(rhs.a1, rhs.a2, rhs.a3);
    }
```

Now, pass that function to your `sort` call:

```
std::sort(vectorA.begin(), vectorA.end(), & predicate);
```

Or to the sort function from your older question:

```
template <class  T>
void sortArray(T record[]) {

    bool swap = true;
    while (swap) {
        swap = false;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize - 1; i++) {
            if (predicate(record[i] ,record[i + 1])) {
                T temp = record[i];
                record[i] = record[i + 1];
                record[i + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately my instructor has said we are not allowed to use <algorithm> to declare our own sort method.

Comment: @Art adapt my example struct and predicate to your type and change the if as I did in the edit

Comment: @art Note that the sorting algorithm given here is brutally inefficient. Your instructor may have made recommendations of sorting algorithms you should use.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you I will write something better.

Comment: @Oblivion I implemented as you said but it I can't seem to get it to sort. It seems to reach the for loop in my sort function but fails once it reaches the if statement. 

   if (predicate(record[i]. ,record[i + 1]))

Comment: @Art you maybe need to change predicate function. For example if you want to sort only based on GPA, then just check the GPA like : `return lhs.GPA < rhs.GPA;` and remove anything else from the function body

Comment: @Oblivion Yes, I did that as part of my testing and had no luck. I created a Record struct with the associated values. In main I created an struct array, struct Record record[3];, and populated the fields. I then passed it to my sortArray function and put in cout statements to know what part of the function they reach and it doesn't seem to get past the IF statement. Thank you for all your help!!!

Comment: I found the mistake! It was comparing lhs against lhs in the if statement of the predicate function.

bool predicate(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) {
    if (lhs.a1 != lhs.a1)
return lhs.firstName > rhs.firstName;
}

should be:
bool predicate(Record const& lhs, Record const& rhs) {
 if (lhs.firstName != rhs.firstName)
  return lhs.firstName > rhs.firstName;
}

Comment: @Art Good catch. That's a frequent mistake when writing custom comparators in my experience. A good alternative may be `std::tie(lhs.a1, lhs.a2, lhs.a3) < std::tie(rhs.a1, rhs.a2, rhs.a3)` - requires a bit less repetition and has way less chance of messing up the logic.

Comment: @Art good catch. I didn't go through your function.